# Database design: primary keys and unique constraints

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I am building my third database and I am unsure how to structure primary keys and unique constraints to ensure data integrity.

The database is updated periodically when public data is released, some monthly, some annually and will have a low query load.

I have some tables where a combination of columns makes each row unique. I am aware that I can use a composite primary key but I am unsure if this is best practise as many of the articles I read on this have conflicting views.

For example, one table requires five columns for uniqueness with datatypes:

- smallint
- char(7)
- varchar(7)
- smallint
- varchar(3)

I believe this would make the primary key up to 25 bytes and all of these five columns will regular be selected and often used in the where clause. One of the smallints is also a foreign key but no foreign keys will reference this table.

The only alternative I am aware of is to create a unique identifier for each row, setting this as the primary key and creating a unique constraint over the five columns.

1. What is the best option and if it is to use a composite primary key should it be clustered or non-clustered?
2. Is there a recommended maximum number of columns and bytes for a composite primary key?

Comment: Since no foreign keys reference this table, there is no downside to a composite clustered primary key.  You just need to decide which column should be the leading one according to how the table is queried,  Then add non-clustered indexes for the remaining columns users may often search on (key or not).

Comment: I presume the leading column should be the one that will be used most in queries? Does the order of the other columns have any relevance?

Comment: Yes, the leading column depends on how the table is queried.  For example, if the foreign key column is a commonly accessed as the many side of a one--to-many identifying relationship, it would make sense to specify that foreign key column as the first one in the primary key.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what is the purpose of your database, but first advise if you can add ,id column as primary key. It'll be easier for every query.

Then If you want just be sur of unique combination of columns in the same table, the easy way is a index with is the keyword UNIQUE:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_COLUMN1_COLUMN2]
ON TABLE(COLUMN1 ASC, COLUMN2ASC);
```

Comment: I can add an ID column but I would prefer to use a composite primary key if possible as this has relevance to the data.

Comment: @Kieran Of course You can keep your composite key. So what about the unique index ? Is solve your problem ?

Comment: An ID column serves no useful purpose here. A unique *constraint*  on the five columns is not optional--it's essential to guarantee data integrity. An ID number alone won't prevent duplication in those five columns.